# reinstalling Google play services?

Tags: google-play-services

My Google Play Services App is missing. Not sure if I deleted it but I'm unable to do almost everything! Please help me figure out how to reinstall Google Play Services (App Icon is shape of puzzle piece)

Comment: Need more information for a more specific answer: What's the phone's make and model?  Is it rooted?  Is it running stock firmware or custom ROM like CyanogenMod, for example?  What exactly are the symptoms - errors, force-closes, etc.?  What exactly lead to this situation?  The more information you can provide, the better we'll be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Google Play Services consists of more than just one app, it's a framework with other moving pieces with some of its parts buried in read-only /system and /data partitions.

If your phone is rooted, the best way to get around such corruption is to re-flash either the factory image, or whichever custom ROM you are running with its corresponding GApps package.  Factory image will have all the necessary components, and for custom ROMs it's the GApps package that contains the Play Services framework and app.

Answer (score -1):

I do not know why the problem happens. But I can tell you one thing that the same thing happened to me too. I was using an android kitkat device, suddenly my google play games app disappeared and I couldn't access several apps. Then I collected the .apk file of google play games app and installed it again. then, everything came to normal again. hope this link helps you.

To assure you even further, this is a link from my personal mediafire account.

Thanks.

http://www.mediafire.com/download/948cu7te39u733n/Google_Play_Games_3.0.11_%281917563-034%29.apk